# JavaScript OR operator effecting setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, operator-keyword

So I have three functions here, they're messing about with each other.

- The first function loads a URL in an element with a fancy effect
- The second function checks an element for adblock
- Finally the third function updates the first function URL every 30 seconds

Take a look:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var update = function(element, url) {
    if ($(element).length) {
        $(element).effect("highlight", {color: "#f7f7f7"}, 2000); $(element).load(url);
   }
}

var adblock = function(adspace) {
    if ($(adspace).height() == 0 || $(adspace).length() <= 1) {
        window.location.replace("../disable-adblock");
    }
}

adblock(".coinurl");       

var refresh_div = setInterval(function() {
    update(".total-plays", "../logs/total-plays.txt");
}, 30000);

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

}); //doc
```

Now the problem is that for some reason the OR (`||`) operator in the second function disables my `setInterval` function. But, when I delete `|| $(adspace).length() <= 1` everything works fine - accept now the adblock function doesn't work with Chrome!

What's going on here? Have I executed the OR statement incorrectly, or is this script in the wrong order?

Thanks

Comment: What, in words, are you actually trying to achieve in `adblock()`?

Comment: As you may know, Adblock collapses an element height to 0 when it detects an ad. This function simply redirects the page when Adblock is detected. It works in Firefox and not in chrome. Even replacing `window.location` with a simple alert does not work. Adblock on chrome bypasses my initial `IF` statement in that function it would seem...

Comment: Let me rephrase. What is the problematic test to the right of `||` supposed to test for?

Comment: I was a little confused. I know you can use `.length` to check if an element exists. I used it incorrectly that's all. Anyway this question is pretty much resolved, thanks.

Comment: The problem is not the presence of `||` *per se* but the expression to the right of it. Get that expression correct and all will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

length is not a function, it is a property

```
var adblock = function(adspace) {
    if ($(adspace).length <= 1 || $(adspace).height() == 0) {
        window.location.replace("../disable-adblock");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. No real errors now, although the page still doesn't redirect to `../disable-adblock` on chrome, why only on firefox? The mystery remains unsolved...

Comment: @LDK try `window.location = "../disable-adblock";`

Comment: Yeah, have just been researching some different location techniques and it seems chrome hates them all. I then tried to perform a simple alert and nothing.